# How to create table in Snowflake using hashdiff, hashbytes, md5

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need solution to create a table with these fields.
I'm not sure for hashidff field. Gives me an errorr there.
Any ideas how to correct the sintakse for Hashdiff field?
I am using Snowflake enviroment.

create TABLE TITLE (
LoanBandKey binary(16) NOT NULL,
HashDiff AS (hashbytes('md5',(CAST(StartDate AS varchar(11))+'|')+CAST(EndDate AS varchar(11))))
);

Comment: HI from where are you getting the columns StartDate and EndDate  ? if you are selecting from a table,  then you need to have a select statement. You can try creating a View and see if that works for you.

Comment: Hi Himanshu Kandpal,
Thanks for your  answer.
That means that we can not create a table with this sintakse? It  will works only with select statements?

Comment: You can create a table using a SELECT statement (CTAS) e.g. CREATE TABLE xxx as SELECT... - the SELECT statement has to be valid, obviously. You can also create a table with calculated columns - but the calculation can only reference other columns in the same table